# Reactive Redis does not continually publish changes to the Flux

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, redis, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am trying to get live updates on my redis ordered list without success.
It seems like it fetches all the items and just ends on the last item.
I would like the client to keep get updates upon a new order in my ordered list.
What am I missing?

This is my code:

```
@RestController
class LiveOrderController {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var redisOperations: ReactiveRedisOperations<String, LiveOrder>

    @GetMapping(produces = [MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE], value = "/orders")
    fun getLiveOrders(): Flux<LiveOrder> {
        val zops = redisOperations?.opsForZSet()
        return zops?.rangeByScore("orders", Range.unbounded())
    }
}
```

Comment: what datatype is zops?

Comment: zops is a ReactiveZSetOperations

Comment: That method doesn't do what you think it does. You need to use pub/sub or keyspace notifications to listen for changes. Worth reading what the reactive API does and the motivations for it - https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Reactive-API-(5.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature in Redis. First, reactive retrieval of a sorted set is just getting a snapshot, but your calls are going in a reactive fashion. So you need a subscription instead.

If you opt in for `keyspace notifications` like this (*K* - enable keyspace notifications, *z* - include zset commands) :

```
config set notify-keyspace-events Kz
```

And subscribe to them in your service like this:

```java
  ReactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer reactiveRedisMessages;
  // ...
  reactiveRedisMessages.receive(new PatternTopic("__keyspace@0__:orders"))
      .map(m -> {
        System.out.println(m);
        return m;
      })
      <further processing>
```

You would see messages like this: `PatternMessage{channel=__keyspace@0__:orders, pattern=__keyspace@0__:orders, message=zadd}`. It will notify you that something has been added. And you can react on this somehow - get the full set again, or only some part (head/tail). You might even remember the previous set, get the new one and send the diff.

But what I would really suggest is rearchitecting the flow in some way to use Redis Pub/Sub functionality directly. For example: publisher service instead of directly calling `zadd` will call `eval`, which will issue 2 commands: `zadd orders 1 x` and `publish orders "1:x"` (any custom message you want, maybe JSON).

Then in your code you will subscribe to your custom topic like this:

```java
return reactiveRedisMessages.receive(new PatternTopic("orders"))
      .map(LiveOrder::fromNotification);
```